# Delphi - Two Modal forms

Tags: delphi

I have a main form (A) that call a modal form (B). and (B) call another modal form (C) and they work normal

the problem when I added new modal form (D) and make it called from (B) then when I close the form (D) the form (B) also closed !! although I made sure the close button modal result = mrnone

please advise

Code:

```
Form A calling B

B := TB.Create(self);
B.ShowModal;

Form B Calling C
C := TC.Create(self);
C.ShowModal;

Form B Calling D
D := TD.Create(self);
D.ShowModal;
```

I use Delphi 2010

More Code added
this is how I free the form that cause the problem and make the caller close !

```
procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  action := cafree;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2 := nil;
end;
```

This is how I show the modal form

```
procedure Tmymodalfrm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  form2 := Tform2.Create(self);
  form2.ShowModal;
end;
```

And after tracing with the call stack I get the code that originally created form B which is so normal:

```
   B := TB.Create(self);
   B.ShowModal;
```

and I am going crazy soon :)

Comment: You've posted no code, and a vague description of the problem. Can you edit to provide more details, and if possible a minimal code same that demonstrated the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Um, no. This isn't code. Something tells A to create B (a button click or menu item), something in  B says to create C, etc. And something back in B says to create D.Put those together in real code, and explain how they're called. (A button click on form A causes form B to be created, which creates form C. How do we get to Form D from here?) Please provide **specific**, compilable code that demonstrates the problem, and explain the sequence of events that gets you there. In what you've provided, once B calls C and shows C modal, B can't call D until C has closed (because C is shown modally).

Comment: @Welliam: Try using `Screen.ActiveForm` instead of `self`.

Comment: at very least if to trust your code you are causing memory leak - you create those forms time and again yet u never free them

Comment: @Arioch You don't know the longevity of the variables. Anyway, no memory leaks because the instances are owned (by one called Self).

Comment: @NGLN yes, and it is bad we were not shown. No, with this logic there si no memory leak at all - every memory belongs to the applciation and would be reclaimed by OS on application life end. I don't see cardinal differense here with "every form belong to some other form and the whole tree will be eventually freed when application terminates and frees FormA"

Comment: @Arioch `C` and `D` are owned by `B`.

Comment: @NGLN and  B - by the same pattern - owned by A. Creation of A not shown, so i assume it was auto-created in .DPR

Comment: A is the main form yes auto created. the project is too big I can not post every thing. I use very simple buttons to call the forms. one button in form B call a modal form C and after it close I can press the other button that call the modal form D.

Comment: @Welliam - please use @ + name  addressing. We are not topicstarters, we would not get auto-notified. // so you show that you create new form each time you display it. Would you show how often and when do you free those forms ? currently it looks liek memory leak

Comment: @Arioch'The I free the form on close action and I debug that and it fire normally I edited the main post with more info. thanks

Comment: Now go to Project Options, Compiler and check "use debug dcus", then clean and build the project - and you would get a muuuuuch more detailed stack trace :-)  BTW, can you in TB.FormCreate check if B=nil or B=self - so nmo double-creation ? Also can you try TB.Create(Application) ?

Comment: @Arioch'The many thanks for your help and follow up I found the reason. written below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. the button that call the form has a modal result = mrclose !!